# How can I redirect to a special page with query string via web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I wrote a web method function for login page. When a user successfully authenticates to a server I want to redirect him to a special page with specified va

```
[WebMethod]
public static string loginmtd(string username, string password , string chk)
{
    datatable dt=filltable();//for bring data
    if (dt.Rows.Count==1)
    {
        if (chk == "ok")
        {
            HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("userauth");
            cook["user"] = usern;
            cook["pass"] = passw;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = 60000;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cook);         
        }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("master.aspx?uid=" + username);       
    return result;     
    }
    else 
    { 
        result = "no";
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know how can i use querystring in webmethod.this code cant redirect to new page and return to main page(loginpg)

Comment: Please take a moment to format your question and code. This will improve your chances to get good answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this on a server side for web methods. This is a client responsibility.

You can follow a different algorithm:

- Call authentication method from client

  - Get authentication token and use it for all subsequent requests
- Call a web method that requires authentication

  - If user doesn't have authentication token, server returns HTTP 401 Not Authorised
  - If user has correct token, server executes web request and returns result + HTTP 200 OK

Also have a look at HTTP status codes [3xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx), they are responsible for redirects that a client may or may not follow.